# Improving efficiency of Recursion in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, recursion

Given this function :

```
e :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
e _ 1 = 1 
e n m 
 |n == m = e n (n-1) 
 |otherwise = e (n-1) m + e n (m-1)
```

If I run it in GHCI, the first evaluation has a huge time e 20 1 takes ~10 seconds, but after that calls to even larger numbers are far reduced, ~0.25 seconds. I assume there is some kind of caching happening?

I kind of see why it explodes because each call to e n m makes two more calls, which then each make two calls, etc. so the number of evaluations eventually gets very large, but a lot of them are just the same reference.

Is there anyway to make Haskell realize this, like some kind of automatic lookup table?

Comment: No there is no caching, this is exactly the reason why this takes that much time.

Comment: You can search this site for `memoization` and see many strategies.  Be sure you compile your program instead of time it in the interpreter when you care about performance.

Comment: You may want to look into the package [memoise](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/memoize-0.8.1/docs/Data-Function-Memoize.html), which provides memoisation tools.

Comment: It is strange that you are seeing the first call take such a long time.  Especially `e 20 1` which ought to reduce immediately.  Try something like `print "hello"` -- does that also take a long time if it's the first thing you do?

Comment: I have to wonder if this recurrence has a closed-form solution.

Answer (score 3):

GHC does *not* magically produce lookup tables for memoization. That said, there are libraries that make this a lot easier. As @AJFarmar suggests, you could use the [`memoize`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/memoize-0.8.1) package.

```
import Data.Function.Memoize

e :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
e = memoFix2 $ \rec -> let e' _ 1 = 1
                           e' n m | n == m = rec n (n-1)
                                  | otherwise = rec (n-1) m + rec n (m-1)
                       in e'
```